# I can’t update my VS Code and get os error 32 each time on my all Windows devices

Tags: visual-studio-code

I make sure all of processes of VS Code have exited, but I can’t delete the bin directory.

I tried many tools to find which process is using the directory, but none of them reported.

The problem occurs on all of my Windows devices and I need to manually update each time.

Comment: [Common issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60697).  If you don't find one of the mentioned programs back on your machine then just use Task Manager and start killing processes one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link suggests a workaround might be to stop Skype for Business:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60697

**Notes**:

- Different users had to close Skype for Business, SkypeBridge, or even f.lux (?)
- Per the link, you can use Windows Process Explorer to determine which apps are holding "bin" open

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was Teams, and found that by searching for Skype in Windows Process Explorer. Killed it and the update went smoothly.

Comment: Thanks mate! It was Microsoft Teams in my case too